# python script for loading csv file to bigquery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am a dataflow beginner using this generic script to load csv file to bigquery using dataflow.

```
import argparse
import csv
import logging

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions
from google.cloud import bigquery


def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--config', dest='config_file', required=True,
                        help='Path to the configuration file')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    # Parse the configuration file
    config = parse_config(known_args.config_file)

    # Create the pipeline options
    options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    google_cloud_options.project = config['project_id']
    google_cloud_options.region = config['region']
    google_cloud_options.staging_location = config['staging_location']
    google_cloud_options.temp_location = config['temp_location']
    google_cloud_options.job_name = config['job_name']
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = config['runner']

    # Create the pipeline
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        # Read the CSV file from GCS
        lines = p | 'Read CSV from GCS' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(config['csv_file'])

        # Write the rows to BigQuery
        lines | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=config['table'],
            schema=config['schema'],
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            project=google_cloud_options.project,
            dataset=config['dataset'],
        )


def parse_config(config_file):
    """Parse the configuration file and return a dictionary of values."""
    config = {}
    with open(config_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('#'):
                continue
            try:
                key, value = line.strip().split('=', 1)
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Error parsing line: {line}")
                raise
            config[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    return config


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

config file:

```
project_id = india-tvm-poc-de
region = us-central1
temp_location = gs://india-tvm-poc-de-123/dataflow_csv/
staging_location = gs://india-tvm-poc-de-123/dataflow_csv/
job_name = csvbqload-dataflow-2
runner = DataflowRunner
csv_file = gs://india-tvm-poc-de-123/dataflow_csv/sample_data.csv
schema = [{"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"}, {"name": "email", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"}]
table = dataflow_load
dataset = sample_dataset
garima_singh@cloudshell:~$ cat config_file.txt
project_id = india-tvm-poc-de
region = us-central1
temp_location = gs://india-tvm-poc-de-123/dataflow_csv/
staging_location = gs://india-tvm-poc-de-123/dataflow_csv/
job_name = csvbqload-dataflow-2
runner = DataflowRunner
csv_file = gs://india-tvm-poc-de-123/dataflow_csv/sample_data.csv
schema = [{"name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"}, {"name": "email", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"}]
table = dataflow_load
dataset = sample_dataset`
```

simple csv file:

```
name,email
John,Doe
Jane,Smith
```

I am getting below error:

> response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type':
> 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri, 05 May 2023 13:10:31
> GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection':
> '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options':
> 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '400',
> 'content-length': '316', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
> "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid value for type: "NAME"
> is not a valid value", "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid value for
> type: "NAME" is not a valid value", "domain": "global", "reason":
> "invalid" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } } > [while running
> 'Write to
> BigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/TriggerLoadJobsWithoutTempTables/ParDo(TriggerLoadJobs)-ptransform-93']

I tried changing the csv file with simple values,removed header int values still getting the error , its a simple script not sure what is the issue
Not sure why the errorr can you please . Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you use dataflow and don't load the CSV file directly in BigQuery?

Comment: I need to create a generic script for loading csv file in bq using dataflow.

Comment: Why dataflow???

Comment: That the requirement given to us.

Comment: The requirement is absurd! Loading a CSV in BigQuery is fast, free (no processing cost)and easy. Here you will set up a cluster of VM to read a file and to write, line by line the content. You will have to spawn the cluster, pay the cluster and pay the streaming write API.

Comment: Do you have high volume in your CSV file ?

Comment: If it’s the case, I am going to propose you a solution with Dataflow soon.

Comment: No, the volume is not high, its normal size. If you can help with the fix it would be really good.

Answer (score 1):

As @GuillaumeBlaquiere said in his comment, if you have a small `CSV` file, no need to use `Dataflow` and it's better to use directly the BigQuery `Python` client.

But if you want or have to stay on `Dataflow` for any reason, I share with you a complete solution that allows to read a `CSV` file with a real `Python` parser in `Beam`.

This class I written allows to read a `CSV` file in `Beam` in a `Dict` :

```py
import codecs
from _csv import QUOTE_ALL
from typing import Iterable, Dict

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import PCollection
from apache_beam.io import fileio
from apache_beam.io.filesystem import CompressionTypes
from apache_beam.io.filesystems import FileSystems as beam_fs


class ReadCsvFiles(beam.PTransform):

    def __init__(self,
                 file_pattern: str,
                 compression_type: CompressionTypes,
                 delimiter=',',
                 quotechar='"',
                 doublequote=True,
                 skipinitialspace=False,
                 lineterminator='\n',
                 quoting=QUOTE_ALL):
        super().__init__()
        self._file_pattern = file_pattern
        self._compression_type = compression_type
        self._delimiter = delimiter
        self._quotechar = quotechar
        self._doublequote = doublequote
        self._skipinitialspace = skipinitialspace
        self._lineterminator = lineterminator
        self._quoting = quoting

    def expand(self, pbegin: beam.pvalue.PBegin) -> PCollection[Dict[str, str]]:
        return (
                pbegin
                | 'Match files' >> fileio.MatchFiles(self._file_pattern)
                | 'Read CSV lines' >> beam.FlatMap(self._read_csv_lines_as_dicts)
        )

    def _get_csv_reader(self, result_file_as_iterator):
        import csv
        return csv.DictReader(
            result_file_as_iterator,
            delimiter=self._delimiter,
            quotechar=self._quotechar,
            doublequote=self._doublequote,
            skipinitialspace=self._skipinitialspace,
            lineterminator=self._lineterminator,
            quoting=self._quoting)

    def _read_csv_lines_as_dicts(self, readable_file_metadata) -> Iterable[Dict[str, str]]:
        
        with beam_fs.open(readable_file_metadata.path, compression_type=CompressionTypes.UNCOMPRESSED) as f:
            import gzip
            if self._compression_type == CompressionTypes.UNCOMPRESSED:
                for row in self._get_csv_reader(codecs.iterdecode(f, 'utf-8')):
                    yield dict(row)
            else:
                with gzip.open(f, "rt") as gzip_text_io_wrapper:
                    for row in self._get_csv_reader(gzip_text_io_wrapper):
                        yield dict(row)
```

This class also handles `csv` compressed as a `gzip` file.

Example of the usage of this class :

```py
result:PCollection[Dict] = (
        p
        | 'Read CSV files' >> ReadCsvFiles('gs://bucket/*.csv', CompressionTypes.UNCOMPRESSED)
        | 'Map after' >> beam.Map(my_map_function))
...
```

I use `fileio.MatchFiles` with Beam then I use `csv.DictReader` to transform the csv line to `Dict`.

You can pass all the CSV file options while you instantiate the `ReadCsvFiles` tranform.

Comment: Have you solved your issue ? If it’s the case please mark the answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because of an issue between the data and the schema.

You can debug by printing the data and validating what you pass to the WriteTobigQuery step.

```
printer = lines | beam.Map(print)
```

You can try changing the schema to a string:

```
'field1:type1,field2:type2,field3:type3'
```

Also, you can try the schema autodetect, and see if it can handle its problem

```
schema="SCHEMA_AUTODETECT",
```